# App threw an error during loading electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-modules

```js
import fetch from "node-fetch";
const electron = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain } = electron;

let mainWindow;
let addWindow;

function createAddWindow() {
  addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    title: "Add Shopping List Item",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "addWindow.js"),
    },
  });
  addWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "addWindow.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );
  // Handle garbage collection
  addWindow.on("close", function () {
    addWindow = null;
  });
}

const mainMenuTemplate = [
  {
    label: "File",
    submenu: [
      {
        label: "Quit",
        accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? "Command+Q" : "Ctrl+Q",
        click() {
          app.quit();
        },
      },
      {
        label: "Add Food",
        accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? "Command+N" : "Ctrl+N",
        click() {
          createAddWindow();
          console.log(__dirname);
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  mainMenuTemplate.push({
    label: "Developer Tools",
    submenu: [
      {
        role: "reload",
      },
      {
        label: "Toggle DevTools",
        accelerator: process.platform == "darwin" ? "Command+I" : "Ctrl+I",
        click(item, focusedWindow) {
          focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
        },
      },
    ],
  });
}

const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);

app.on("ready", function () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false, // is default value after Electron v5
      contextIsolation: true, // protect against prototype pollution
      enableRemoteModule: false, // turn off remote
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "addWindow.js"), // use a preload script
    },
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "mainWindow.html"),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );
});

global.foods = [];

ipcMain.on("item:add", (e, item) => {
  if (global.foods) {
    global.foods.push(item);
  }
  let params = {
    api_key: "hufCDnLVnrKMT18TsIPBJYVDnzwyQaLyKfLE9Q6c",
    query: item,
    dataType: [" Survey (FNDDS)"],
    pagesize: 5,
  };

  let api_url = `https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v/foods/search?api_key={encodeURIComponent(params.api_key)}&query=${encodeURIComponent(
    params.query
  )}&dataType=${encodeURIComponent(
    params.dataType
  )}&pageSize=${encodeURIComponent(params.pagesize)}`;

  function getData() {
    return fetch(api_url).then((response) => response.json());
  }

  getData().then((data) => console.log(data.foods[0]).foodNutrients);

  addWindow.close();
});
```

Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "count-it-lose-it",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Lose weight , workout , calorie counter",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "Keegan Albert",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "electron": "^20.0.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.10"
  },
  "type": "module"
  
}
```

App threw an error during load
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module F:\workout app\main.js from F:\workout app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js not supported.
Instead change the require of F:\workout app\main.js in F:\workout app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
at loadApplicationPackage (F:\workout app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:110:16)
at Object. (F:\workout app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:222:9)
at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)
at Object. (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:185:3104)
at ./lib/browser/init.ts (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:185:3308)
at **webpack_require** (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:1:128)
at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:1:1200
at node:electron/js2c/browser_init:1:1267
at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13343)

this is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried requiring fetch instead of importing it?

`const fetch = require("node-fetch")`

and removing `type: "module"` from package.json

EDIT: you should install `electron` as a dev dependency, since it will most likely be required later to package it for production.